# I try to send a noficiation per cloud messaging but it doesn´t work

Tags: firebase, http, request, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I tried to sent a notification with fcm but I still get the error:

> The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section "Authentication" of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.

I tried it with postman and with a http post in my angular project. I have an authentication key (my server-key from firebase) that's why I can't understand the problem.

```
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Content-Type","application/json");
  headers.append("Authorization","key=xxxx");

  let Options = new RequestOptions({headers : headers , body :{
      "registration_ids" : ["eO2Ht66UA6Y:APA91bFTKf0C701O4nXHYz7sdlh62pwG01X5apE8Ri_iEPkotonRE2vHzJQwXn2YjiJ7XtIYBT3pNK1VfnJ2zhjtd1k2kn2tqs4zoMl23DJd6XG1GFd0r9Jda5N-bO0B9gERi4xhtadj"],
          "data" : {
          "message" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
      }}});

  this.http.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',Options).first().subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
  }
```

Comment: Did you really mean to put your authentication key in your question?

Comment: my authentication key isn´t in my question

Comment: OK.  Well, is that "registration id" proprietary information?

Comment: Also, I know you don't want to share your authentication key, but perhaps you can show us where you're inserting it in your code?  (use xxx, [redacted], or whatever)